# Oracle create type table from existing table%rowtype?

Tags: oracle, pipeline, table-functions

I'm trying to create a test pipelined table function.  In the first declaration then i am receiving the following error:

"Identifier LOADER.SD_DIM_DATE must be declared."

How do I create a type based on an existing object, ie a table or cursor?

```
create type tDateDim AS table of LOADER.SD_DIM_DATE%ROWTYPE;
/
create or replace function tvf_DateDimm
return LOADER.SD_DIM_DATE%ROWTYPE pipelined is
begin
  FOR i in (select * from LOADER.SD_DIM_DATE) loop
    pipe row(I.REPORT_MONTH, I.REPORT_MONTH_DESC)
  end loop;
  return;
end;
```

Comment: Well, does LOADER.SD_DIM_DATE exist and do you have permission to see it - can you query it? Presumably LOADER is a schema and SD_DIM_DATE is a table, right? (This won't work anyway - `%rowtype` is a PL/SQL construct, you can't use it in a schema-level SQL-context code)

Comment: Ok, thanks am trying to create a table type based on an existing object like a table.  Yes Loader is the schema, thanks for the info.

Comment: I am trying to understand how they work.  Do I have to create an explicit custom type each time I want to create a pipelined function, ie if I want to return a dataset that's got lot's of columns.  All examples online are very generic and use examples that don't seem practical.  ie, iterating from 1 .. 10 etc...I'd like an example of returning data from a table or cursor or query ... I'm not even sure if this is possible...